# why can't we use ROWID as primary key?

Tags: oracle, primary-key, rowid

According to [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm)

> You should not use ROWID as the primary key of a table. If you delete
> and reinsert a row with the Import and Export utilities, for example,
> then its rowid may change. If you delete a row, then Oracle may
> reassign its rowid to a new row inserted later.

I didn't understand the actual reason. Does it mean, when we use Import/Export utilities, then only we shouldn't use ROWID as primary key or we should never use ROWID as primary key ?

As explained above, when we delete the row and re-insert then same ROWID may get assign but on the other side the row was already deleted, so there won't be any problem if we get same ROWID. Isn't it ? Can anyone explain this with some example ?

Comment: In the delete scenario, imagine what happens to all the data in other tables that referenced the original row by its rowid.

Comment: If we have used `cascade delete` then  ?

Comment: Yes. Or if you have data in another system that uses the same reference. And the export/import scenario is not the only one that causes rowid changes. Table moves ("reorg") also does.

Comment: You can't create an actual primary key using rowid (you'd get 'invalid identifier'); so I think it means not to treat is as such, by assuming it's never going to change ([since it can](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:53140678334596)).

Answer (score 4):

If you rebuild your table then the ROWID of the table may change and you dont want your primary key to be changed.

Also if you delete one record then a new record could be given that ROWID. Also you should understand that ROWID does not persist across a database EXPORT and IMPORT process.

From [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rowids-for-plsql-performance.php)

> If rows are moved, the ROWID will change. Rows can move due to
>   maintenance operations like shrinks and table moves. As a result,
>   storing ROWIDs for long periods of time is a bad idea. They should
>   only be used in a single transaction, preferably as part of a SELECT
>   ... FOR UPDATE, where the row is locked, preventing row movement.

Comment: But apparently this can only happen if "enable row movements" is enabled...

Answer (score 0):

We should never use ROWIDs as primary keys for permanent and business-important data.

ROWID is a technical address of a row. There are several scenarious when

a) rowid of the existing records would be changed

b) different records would have the same rowid.

For example, if you have partitioned table, updating of record's partitioning key would bring us into record's rowid changing. Such scenarious prevents of using ROWID keys unless we can to forget it without serious consequences.

ROWID keys can be used for unnecessary temporary data, such as exceptions tables, or for short-term navigation, such as in `WHERE CURRENT OF` clause.